# Combine function arguments in a new function in R

Tags: r, function

I would like to combine different arguments of a function (e.g. `read.table`) in a single function.

Normally, I would have the following code to load a dataframe:

```
df <- read.table(path_to_file, header=TRUE, colClasses = c("numeric", "numeric"), na.strings = "None")
```

If I would like to load multiple different dataframes, I retype all arguments:

```
df2 <- read.table(path_to_file, header=TRUE, colClasses = c("numeric", "numeric"), na.strings = "None")
df3 <- read.table(path_to_file, header=TRUE, colClasses = c("numeric", "numeric"), na.strings = "None")
```

However, I would like to combine the `header`, `colClasses` and `na.strings` arguments in a function, so that I do not have to re-type all arguments. I tried the following code, but it does not work:

```
x <- function(){
header=TRUE
colClasses = c("numeric", "numeric")
na.strings = "None"
}

df <- read.table(path_to_file, x())
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply wrap it around a new function like this

```
read.table2 = function(path_to_file){
  read.table(path_to_file, header=TRUE, 
             colClasses = c("numeric", "numeric"), 
             na.strings = "None")
}

df = read.table2(path_to_file)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some alternatives:

**1) purrr::partial**  The `partial` function in `purrr` can be used to create a new function with specified arguments already set.

```
library(purrr)

my.read.table <- partial(read.table, 
  header = TRUE, colClasses = c("numeric", "numeric"), na.strings = "None")

my.read.table("myfile.dat")
```

The `Curry` function in the functional package and the `set.defaults` function in the diversitree package are similar.  Also see `setDefaults` in the quantmod package for a related approach.

**2) wrapper**  This wrapper changes the defaults of the indicated arguments while retaining the ability to override them further.

```
my.read.table.2 <- function(..., 
  header = TRUE, colClasses = c("numeric", "numeric"), na.strings = "None") {

  read.table(..., header = header, colClasses = colClasses, na.strings = na.strings)
}

my.read.table.2("myfile.dat")
```